# What are the 365 virtues?

Tags: greek, myth-identification, comparative, aztec, hebrew

I was researching and I came across Abraxas, a daemon(inferior god), an archon, an aeon, the "Supreme" god, an angel...

He has a place in many mythologies, and the number 365 keeps coming up. 365 heavens, spheres, numbers, archons, skies, powers of imagined heavens, days of the year(a given), numeric value, spirits, others and virtues.

Is there a list of what any of the sets are(i.e., the 365 heavens, powers, virtues...)?

Comment: Great question.  I'll need to do some research to refresh my memory on this topic, which, like you, I have come across in numerous contexts. 
 (In the meantime: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraxas_(album)  :)

Answer (score 2):

365 Genii of Earthly Spheres, the Greek calendar divided it so. Also Abraxas stood for the 7 Sphere Archons, or the Planetary Rulers that in some traditions were 'imprisoning' by misunderstanding, while in others they were shaping the human spirit/soul before it was released onto further voyage. Like in Mithraic mysteries, the soul entered from the stars Northwards, passing Saturn down to Earth, and the exit was Southwards - back to the Heavens, after passing through the gates of archons. My persona speculation is that Abraxas stood for the Seven Shining Ones, guardians of the body of Osiris (Sah, or Orion Constellation). Abraxas is related strictly to gnostic and Egypto-Hellenic magick.