# Who says Abraxas is a prince of hell?

Tags: myth-identification, comparative, christianity

I asked a previous question about Abraxas [here](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/3352/what-are-the-365-virtues), briefly talking about what he is and asking how the number 365 relates to him in so many ways.

A few days later, I was talking to someone who happened to look at my computer as I was researching. We had a conversation on what I had found out about him (her, by some sources). After I said my piece, she said Abraxas was also a prince of Hell. I've been trying to connect him since, but haven't found anything related or worth mentioning.

Where can I find information about Abraxas being a prince of Hell?

Answer (score 3):

It was not uncommon for the Catholic Church to brand pagan deities as demons. To that effect, Abraxas is listed with several other pagan deities in [J. Collin de Plancy's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Collin_de_Plancy) [*Dictionnaire Infernal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionnaire_Infernal) (Infernal Dictionary). Here's an illustration from the 6th edition:

[image: Abraxas from Infernal Dictionary, 6th Edition, 1863]

I have not found a source calling Abraxas a *prince of Hell*, specifically. If you allow a guess, I'll say that the characterization may at least partly derive from Abraxas's regal appearance in the above illustration (notice the crown?).